# How do I see client connections in AWS Aurora (MYSQL) to both reader and writer?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to find a count/list of all user connections to both the reader and writer instance. I understand that show full processlist; will give me a list of connected users, but it won't show me what host a user is connected to.

I would love to do this with a SQL statement if it's possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think `information_schema.PROCESSLIST` contains the information.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST;
```

This table has `HOST` column, it should have client IP address.

Comment: that will only show me the client IP, not the server IP

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that `show full processlist;` will give me a list of connected users, but it won't show me what host a user is connected to.

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` shows only the connections to the specific Aurora instance that you are connected to when you run the query.

To retrieve the clients for the entire cluster, you need to connect to each instance in the cluster, and run the same query.